# speed of vechile in veins increases slowly

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm using veins 4.4, OMNeT++ 5.0 and SuMO 0.25. I have set vehicle speed to 0 to stop them by `traciVehicle->setSpeed(0)` then after certain case i set them to 20 by `traciVehicle->setSpeed(20)` to cross the intersection but for no reason it increases slowly till its time finish , so can i make it faster ???

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you quantify how slow exactly the speed increases? How does this value compare to what you expected?

Comment: The max acceleration speed of a car is specified by the vehicleType used in SUMO. Maybe it's worth to look on this values and compare them to your speed increasing.

Comment: Actually i solved the problem by regenerating my map and after that vehicles crossed in same speed.i think unknown error occurred in my (.net or .rou ) files while i was debugging my code. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

A vehicle in SuMO has the [`speedMode`](http://www.sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_Vehicle_State#speed_mode_.280xb3.29) parameter which determines how it should behave for instance in terms of acceleration and deceleration.

By default this parameters is set to consider all checks like keeping a safe gap to other vehicles and the maximum acceleration. When set to 0 the vehicle ignores all checks like the maximum acceleration.

Try setting different values for the `speedMode` in Veins to achieve the expected vehicle behavior. You can do so by using the [TraCICommandInterface](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h) and the [TraciVehicle](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIMobility.h). Have a look at the [TraCITestApp](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCITestApp.cc) for an example. Also you could play around with the `maximumSpeed` parameter.

Comment: Good Point , i will try to use it in controlling speed but how to set speedMode , i saw in TestAPP something like 0x00, didn't get it??

Comment: You can find the values and there meaning in the documentation I linked in my answer. Please see the TraciTestApp for setting such a value in Veins.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by regenerating my map and after that vehicles crossed in its expected speed.i think unknown error occurred in my (.net or .rou ) files while i was debugging my code.