# How to control the transmission power and speed based on the distance between two vehicles in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am a beginner about Veins. Now I am trying to simulate dynamic adjustment of the transmission power and speed between 2 running vehicles based on their distance with each other with Veins 4.5, Omnet 5.0 and Sumo 0.29.
So far I have built the Sumo model and run the model in Omnet but without any programming which means the transmission power and speed between 2 vehicles are all set in the .ini file. Now I want to implement an algorithm to adjust them dynamically.
As a beginner I barely know how to start this job. The Veins tutorial didn't tell how to apply the functions provided by Veins. I now build a new .cc file based on our .ned file. And from MyVeinsApp.cc I found some methods I need to implement. But still I need some programming instructions about my problem.
1 how to get the realtime distance between 2 running vehicles?
2 is it possible to control the transmission power and speed with Veins 4.5?

I am sorry for these initial questions.But I really don't know how to develop a Veins simulation from the very beginning step by step at the programming level

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is this question answered?

Answer (score 2):

To get the distance between two vehicles you can use the built-in function `distance()` from [*Coord*](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/base/utils/Coord.h) (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687283/calculating-distance-between-cars-nodes-veins/42695192#42695192)).

To control the transmit power you can use the parameter `txPower` from [*Mac1609_4*](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.ned#L59).

For changing the speed of the vehicle you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057528/speed-of-vechile-in-veins-increases-slowly).

Comment: Thank you very much! So far I have a few submodules in my NED file and all of them are the existing modules in Veins, such as ConnectionManager，TraciScenrioMangerLaunchd. Should I modify the corresponded cc file of them or implement my algorithm in my own cc file? if the latter, how can I connect my cc file with my NED file? It is a Network in which I can't use @class in it.

Comment: Please start with OMNeT's [TicToc Tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/) to find out how to work with modules and setup a simulation. For your algorithms you can create a new module or use *MyVeinsApp*.

Comment: Thank you very much.  When I added a MyVeinsApp into my NED file without adding any code into MyVeinsApp.cc and ran the simulation, it just crashed with the exit code 255. And I deleted the MyVeinsApp submodule, everything is ok again. Why did this happen? I thought it should be ok.  I mean the existing submodules are necessary to run my SUMO model. What I want is how to add a new submodule into my NED file and program in the related cc file. The Tictoc taught me how to build a simulation step by step but no instructions to deal with this situation.

Comment: Can you rephrase what exactly you did and what you are trying to do?